# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'src'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Let's say my app looks like this

```
├── index.js
└── src
    ├── do_foo.js
```

**do_foo.js**

```js
function foo() {
    return "bar";
}

export default foo;
```

**index.js**

```js
import foo from 'src/do_foo';

foo();
```

Running `node index.js` results in the following error

```sh
> node index.js

internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'src' imported from /mnt/c/Users/*******/Projects/*******/index.js
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:620:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:659:14)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:752:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:49:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fetch_courses@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the *******@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/*******/.npm/_logs/2020-07-21T03_38_34_404Z-debug.log
```

Seeing as I've managed to mess up at such an early point, the solution, I'd imagine, has to be pretty simple. What cardinal rule of javascript am I violating here?

I should add that I know everything will work if everything is in the same folder, but that's not what I'm aiming for. If at all possible, it's a better look to keep `index.js` in the outermost directory.

Edit: I want to clear up that my problem was **NOT** caused by a typo. My code was syntactically fine, it was the import that needed a relative scope. I mistyped something when I was writing the example code, that had nothing to do with the initial question.

Comment: 1) Get your quotes right. 2) Use a relative path, ie `import foo from './src/do_foo'`

Comment: oh i typed everything from scratch to make it minimally reproducible - must have been a typo @Phil

Comment: you answered my question, the one you linked is about making imports readable and they never ran into any kind of error @Phil

Comment: True. I'm sure there's an applicable duplicate out there somewhere though 

Comment: im still happy to give you credit if you post an answer @Phil

Comment: imo this question is worth leaving up because nothing came up when i searched for the stack trace in the first place

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use the full file path to get this working.

```
import foo from './src/do_foo.js';

console.log(foo());
```

Since its an experimental feature, you will get this warning.

```
ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
```

Comment: i dont get any kind of warning

Comment: What about when you hit this in a monorepo...?

Comment: As of node 14 esm module support in node is now stable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using typescript, in the tsconfig change "module":"esnext" for "module":"commonjs" and in the package.json  "module":"commonjs".

Answer (score 0):

This is is another way, albeit basic.

In your foo.js

You can run `module.exports = foo;`

In your index.js you can run

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const foo = require(__dirname + "/foo.js");

foo();
```